# Sequelize add attribute as boolean if id in list of ids

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to query a table and if the column id exists in another table, want to mark as boolean means usable or not. How to achieve this? It doesnt work because sequelize.col("id") doesnt return an id. Association is one to many. One bonus hasMany BonusActions.

Returned value is

> Col:{col:id}

```
    let bonuses = await Modelx.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: ["name", "leading_bonus", "id"],

    include: [
      {
        model: db.bonus_action,
        where: {
          id: {
            [Op.notIn]:
              actions_daily_used.rows
                .map((x) => x.actionId)
                .concat(actions_once_used.rows.map((x) => x.actionId)) ?? [],
          },
        },
        attributes: [
          "id",
/******** HERE *******/
          [
           
            actions_once_used.rows.some(
              (x) => x.BonusAction.id === db.sequelize.col("id")
            ) ||
            actions_daily_used.rows.some(
              (x) => x.BonusAction.id === db.sequelize.col("id")
            )
              ? db.Sequelize.literal("false")
              : db.Sequelize.literal("true"),
            "is_usable",
          ],
        ],
      },
      
     
    ],

  });
```

Comment: You can use `CASE WHEN` SQL with `literal`. Although mysql doesn't have boolean datatypes, so you can only get tinyint like 1/0 or string literal "true"/"false". To convert to boolean, you need a custom function in js side.